# Why preg_match() always validates as true when partial match?

Tags: php, regex

Recently been explerimenting with regular expressions and when I've tried to confirm that the `preg_match()` function was not returning the expected result (`false`). I've realised that my regex would evaluate to true with both a partial and full match.

Can anyone more experienced share some comments on why this is working like this?

I've tested this using the following code:

```
<?php

# Storing regexp.
$pattern = "/Banana|Apples/i";

# Storing value that will be compared against regexp.
$value = "Chiiiiiiiibanana";

# Testing how preg_match is dealing with the regexp.
if (preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches)) {
    echo "It's a match!\n";

    # In case there's matches, print them.
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo "Sorry, not a match.";
}

?>
```

In this case regex returns `1` (true) although "`bananas`" as "`Chiiiiiiii`" prefixing it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Start of a string is `^`

Comment: You must be looking for anchors: `^` and `$`. `$pattern = "/^(?:Banana|Apples)$/i";` See http://ideone.com/cqDAs5

Comment: Any more details on why I should use anchor (I'll research more about it after), also why the ? metacharacter if there's nothing preceding it?

Thank you.

Comment: You are only saying does this string contain `banana`. It does so it is true. Use anchors and you say does this string only contain `banana` (or apples). You also might want to make that `s` optional on apples.

Comment: Just tested your regexp works but since I want to understand what's going on I'm still looking to learn more. I'll read a bit more about it.

So thankful. @stribizhev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid any  partial matches, you must use anchors:

- `^` - start of a string
- `$` - end of string.

So  use

```
$pattern = "/^(?:Banana|Apples)$/i";
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/cqDAs5)

Since you have an alternative list, you need to group them so that the anchors apply  correctly, not just to the first and last alternatives. If you use `"/^Banana|Apples$/i"`, `banana` will be matched in `bananas` and `apples` in `=apples`.

To only group alternatives but not store in any capture groups, a non-capturing group can be used (`(?:....)`). Moreover, you do not need capturing groups set on the entire pattern since the whole match text is always stored inside Group 0.

Comment: Great and informative answer. However, ideone links tend to disappear after a while (this I've learned recently). It may be best (that's if you want), to include the actual code for it, should that link no longer be made available.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I know that but the code is already in this post: OP's code with my modification works as expected.

Comment: No problemo. Just a "sidenote" ;-)